# Add word under cursor to search pattern

Tags: vim

Using <kbd>*</kbd> when the cursor is on a word `theWord`, vim directly jumps to the next appearance of exactly that word, i.e. performes `/\<theWord\>`.

**Questions:**

Is there a way to add another word `otherWord` to the search, when the cursor is on this other word, such that one performes `/\<theWord\>\|\<otherWord\>`?

Comment: Off-topic, but thanks for letting me know this simple shortcut! I learn everyday with vim :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: You're not alone ;) Just have a look at this: http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/vimtips.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try something like:

1. <kbd>*</kbd> (to search for a word)
2. move somewhere else
3. `:let @/=@/.'\|\<'.expand("<cword>").'\>'` this appends to the previous search pattern the current word under the cursor) with some delimiters (`\|` and the word boundaries...)
4. if you want to, set up a hotkey for it, like: `nnoremap <F4> :let @/.='\\|\<'.expand("<cword>").'\>'<CR>`

Comment: Greate!! Exactly what I was looking for, in particular 4.)! Please put another escape `\` before `\|`, i.e. `\\|` to make it work.

Comment: I needed `nmap <F4> :let @/=@/.'\\|\<'.expand("<cword>").'\>'<CR>`. So double backslash before pipe

Comment: You should always prefer `nnoremap` to `nmap` when possible. And BTW, `:let` supports `.=` now.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte Isn't nnoremap==nmap ? Why it's better? Thank you.

Comment: The `nore` mappings and abbreviations protects against side effects. Search for "remapping". Here, if some user of your mapping decide to remap `:` into `;` and the other way around, the mapping won't work any more -- yes, sometimes people have strange configuration.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte Thank you very much for your response. I was thinking that's just an abbreviation. I tested it and yes, its not, it's working differently
:map j gg
:map Q j
:nmap W j
:nnoremap X j

Again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
:nnoremap <silent> + :let @/ .= '\\|\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<cr>n
```

That will append the word under the cursor to the search register when '+' is hit, and jump to the **n**ext occurrence of any searched pattern.

If you wish to extend it to the visual mode, (as [it could be done to n_star](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/v_star.vim)), you have

```
:vnoremap <silent> + <c-\><c-n>:let @/ .= '\\|'.escape(lh#visual#selection(), '/\^$*.[~')<cr>n
```

With [`lh#visual#selection()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/visual.vim#L51) to fetch the current selection, and `escape()` to neutralize some active characters in regexes. `v_CTRL-\_CTRL-N` being a safe and silent escape sequence.

Comment: Any explanation on what you are doing here would be really appreciated. Don't just want to copy and paste something. Cheers!

Comment: The `:help` command permits to ask vim precisions on what you don't already know, -> `:h nnoremap`, `:h :let`, `:h .=`, `:h expand()`, or `:h n`, `:h @/`
NB: <cr> concludes the command-mode.

Comment: And that's why it is called answer and not hint?! ;)

Comment: Well you already knew '\|', where to start then ? This line is extremely simple and does not need much explanations. There is no trick (outside the use of `<cr>`, and the odd behaviour of `\|`)

Comment: The link for the visual selection is broken, use this instead: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/visual.vim#L53